# MySql and operator in parenthesis and or operator out of parenthesis

Tags: mysql

I am studying the MySql [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-rows.html) and saw the code below:

`mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE (species = 'cat' AND sex = 'm')
    -> OR (species = 'dog' AND sex = 'f');`

Output:

```
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| name  | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
| Claws | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL  |
| Buffy | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL  |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------+
```

From my understanding of the `OR` operator it should return the first true value and perform lazy evaluation. Why does it return two true values in the above table, two records and not one.

Any references to official documentation would be helpful.

Comment: It's not a mysql problem, it's a logical problem. The condition is the whole thing after the WHERE key word. It's either true or false, there's no "just the first part is true". If a row matches the whole condition, it's returned.

Comment: This does not contradict lazy evaluation … the first record satisfies the first partial condition `(species = 'cat' AND sex = 'm')`, so here we can be “lazy” and put it into our result set, no matter what the second condition yields (because they are conjoined by `OR`). The second record doesn’t satisfy that condition, so no laziness allowed here, we _have_ to check the second partial condition too. Oh look, it matches `(species = 'dog' AND sex = 'f')`, so it goes into our result set as well – again, _because_ there’s an `OR` between those two partial conditions.

Comment: If `(species = 'cat' AND sex = 'm')` matches a result set why does the OR continue with `(species = 'dog' AND sex = 'f')` ? In plain english OR signifies an alternative if something is not present. Example: Have and apple `or` a banana.

Comment: Every single record _on its own_ is checked against the _whole_ WHERE clause condition to determine whether it is to be included into the result set or not. Or to take your simplified example, let’s say we have a table with just one column `fruit` and it contains three records with values `apple`, `banana` and `orange` respectively, and we have a WHERE clause `WHERE fruit = 'apple' or fruit = 'banana'` […]

Comment: […] First record, value `apple` -> satisfies first part of our condition -> goes into the result set. Second record, value `banana` -> doesn’t satisfy first part of our condition, but satisfies the second one -> goes into the result set. Third record, value `orange` -> doesn’t satisfy first part of our condition, doesn’t satisfy second part -> does not go into the result set. Does that make it clearer to you …?

Comment: OK understand. Thanks!

Comment: What would happen if instead of the `or` there was an `and`?

Comment: Never mind just ran the query and thought out the logic. I am good now.

Comment: Good you got it. But be careful, *In plain english* is the easiest way to hit the wall. Logical sequents do not always run under the same interpretation range than plain english. Example: Are you coming today OR tomorrow? If I answer you "yes" you might be confused for a few seconds...